# Find the average. largest, smallest number and mode of a int array

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to make a program where the user can enter up to 25 numbers and then it tells the user the average, smallest and largest number and the mode of the numbers entered but I am not sure on how to do this.

Any Guidance would be appreciated

here is what I have so far

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("enter the amount of numbers you would like to use of: ");
        int arraylength = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] AverageArray = new int[25];

        //filling the array with user input
        for (int i = 0; i < AverageArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("enter the numbers you wish to find the average for: ");
            AverageArray[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }
        //printing out the array 
        Console.WriteLine("here is the average: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < AverageArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(AverageArray[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(FindAverage(AverageArray));
    }


    public static double FindAverage(int[] averageNumbers)
    {
        int arraySum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < averageNumbers.Length; i++)
            arraySum += averageNumbers[i];

        return arraySum / averageNumbers.Length;
    }
    public static double LargestNumber(int[] Nums, int Count)
    {

    }
    public static double SmallestNumber(int[] Nums, int Count)
    {

    }
    public static double Mode(int[] Nums, int Count) 
    {

    }
    }
```

Comment: Is this for homework?

Comment: what specifically are you having problems with?  If you got that far it seems like you should be able to get the rest.  Unless there's something specific that you're struggling with.

Comment: Googling with jus the keywords would have taken less time and effort. There are so many results available

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
public static double LargestNumber(int[] Nums, int Count)
{
    double max = Nums[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < Count; i++)
        if (Nums[i] > max) max = Nums[i];

    return min;
}
public static double SmallestNumber(int[] Nums, int Count)
{
    double min = Nums[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < Count; i++)
        if (Nums[i] < min) min = Nums[i];

    return min;
}
public static double Mode(int[] Nums, int Count) 
{
    double mode = Nums[0];
    int maxCount = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) 
    {
       int val = Nums[i];
       int count = 1;
       for (int j = i+1; j < Count; j++)
       {
          if (Nums[j] == val) 
             count++;
       }
       if (count > maxCount) 
       {
            mode = val;
            maxCount = count;
       }
    }
    return mode;
}
```

Comment: The question is not a technical problem but a task or similar that a lazy developer try to avoid. The idea is to enhance their skills with correct answers, not to help them to be more lazy.

Answer (score 0):

```
var smallest = AverageArray.Min();
var largest = AverageArray.Max();
var mode = AverageArray.GroupBy(v => v)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .First()
            .Key;
```

Comment: Based on the fact that he wrote the average function himself, I doubt he wants to use built ins.

Comment: That's kind of a wild assumption to make. He could easily be new to C# and unaware of the power of LINQ. In which case, now would be a perfect time to understand that in programming its rarely desirable to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Loocid Then he should have said that in his question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to use linq

```
   /*Assign Initial Value*/
        int highestNum = numberArray[0];
        int lowestNum = numberArray[0];
        int sum = 0;

        foreach (int item in numberArray)
        {
            /*Get The Highest Number*/
            if (item > highestNum)
            {
                highestNum = item;
            }
            /*Get The Lowest Number*/
            if (item < highestNum)
            {
                lowestNum = item;
            }
            //get the sum
            sum = item + sum;
        }            

        //display the Highest Num
        Console.WriteLine(highestNum);
        //display the Lowest Num
        Console.WriteLine(lowestNum);
        //Display The Average up to 2 decimal Places
        Console.WriteLine((sum/numberArray.Length).ToString("0.00"));
```